# Complications in Migrating DB from Sql Server 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I'm planning to upgrade DB from Sql Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edn but confused with the choice of OS? SQL server 2000 is running on Win 2000 Server and I'm setting up a new machine with either Win 2003 or Win 2008R2 standard edition in which I'll install SQl server 2008 Ent Edn and migrate the SQL2000 db to sql 2008. So what will be the best Windows OS for this machine? Any suggestion regarding what problems I can face from SQL server upgradation?

Answer (score 1):

Few things come to my mind but not as a complete list though.

Memory management is much better between OS & SQL Server in Win 2008 R2.
Disk alignment is much better when compared to windows 2000/2003 where you have to manually check and very careful with boundary alignment. Windows 2008 R2 takes care of that stuff for you.

PS: I haven't done any migrations using Windows 2008 R2 yet.